# MyWindow=window.open using pop windows and return to parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using two buttons in my web page (http://localhost:8088/hse/public/explorer) :

and those button will open a new pop window : (http://localhost:8088/hse/public/explorer/1)

```
onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://localhost:8088/hse/public/explorer/1','MyWindow',width=300,height=200); return false;">Show Map</button>
```

This button on clicked it will open a new pop window and inside that pop windows, there will be some HTML links, i want when user click on any of those link , the pop windows close and that link open on the same parent page but different URL (http://localhost:8088/hse/public/explorer/show/1)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: First of all, pop up windows may likely be blocked by browsers. And, you may want split js code from html since it's quite complex now. You may need have a look at `postMessage` or some thing other tech by searching "javascript communicate between tabs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this.**

> This wont work when you run the "snippet" ... Create a document and use it there instead.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = evt => {
    
    window.open(window.location.origin + "/hse/public/explorer/1", "MyWindow", "width=300, height=200");
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Open new window</button>
```

**Update:**

Try doing this instead what you described down below. This will do the same, but actually makes sense to use. If you want to create something that is ensured to be userfriendly.

```js
var id_button     = document.getElementById("button"),
    id_container  = document.getElementById("container");

id_button.onclick = evt => {
    // show or hide container
    if (id_container.classList.contains("hide")) {
        
        id_container.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        
        id_container.classList.add("hide");
    }
}

// add onclick-function for every child of "id_container"
for (var i = 0; i < id_container.childElementCount; i++) {
    
    var child_element = id_container.children[i];
    
    child_element.onclick = evt => {
        
        // check that the element is a "a"-element
        if (evt.target.localName == "a") {
        
            window.open(window.location.origin + evt.target.getAttribute("data-link"), "_blank");   
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Show/hide all links</button>
<br><br>
<div id="container" class="container hide">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/hse/public/explorer/1">Link1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/hse/public/explorer/2">Link2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="/hse/public/explorer/3">Link3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What i want is a javascript code for a <a> links in opened windows , is that user one click on any link , the current opened windows will be closed and the link to be opened in same windows that he referred from :- 
Page 1 (Parent) on that page user will click on button "document.getElementById("button").onclick = evt => {" then page 2 will open , inside page 2 there will be a link , i want the user when click on link in page 2 the page 2 will close and open that link in page 1

Comment: OK, that is a lot of bother to do, and why would you? You can not close another window from a site unless you use some server code and a live listener. And from what I read at the moment, that would be allot of work for you at this stage. If you want to learn more, I suggest you try learning Firebase. Why would you open an external window from page 1, then close page 2 and open a new tab in the same window as page 1? I will give you a much easier way to open links in a new tab. I will update my answer.

Comment: Because , in second windows it will open a picture based map , and this map need a full screen view, thanks for your suggestion i will look for firebase

Comment: @user2873860 OK, I understand. If you use Firebase, you can easily add servercode and experiment a little for free. And as said use live listeners. You need some type of connection between two websites if you want to close an external window, this is why a live listener can be optimal to use. You'll find all the tutorials to get started on their YouTube account.